# Laravelをhttps化したら、postができなくなった

Tags: php, aws, apache, laravel, https

以下のように構成を変更したところ、post、laravel socialiteを利用したtwitter認証ができなくなりました。

**変更前:**

- cloudfront → ALB → EC2

**変更後:**

- https~ → cloudfront → ALB → EC2
  https~はCertificate Managerで発行

下記の処理を用いて、routes/web.phpにてassetヘルパー関数のhttps化は行っています。

```
if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
 URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

原因は恐らくhttps化の前後で、postまたはtwitter認証後のredirect時のRequest($request)内の#session:Storeの値が異なるからではないかと考えていますが、解決方法がわかりません。

この問題を一向に解決できずに、大変苦労しております。
恐れ入りますが、解決方法をご教授して頂きますと幸いです。

##### https化前

```
#session: Store {#▼
#id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
#name: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_session"
#attributes: array:4 [▼
  "_flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
  "_token" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  "url" => array:1 [▼
    "intended" => "http://XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX"
  ]
  "_previous" => array:1 [▼
    "url" => "http://XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX"
  ]
]
#handler: DatabaseSessionHandler {#▶}
#started: true}
```

##### https化後

```
#session: Store {#▼
#id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
#name: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_session"
#attributes: [
  "_token" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]
#handler: DatabaseSessionHandler {#▶}
#started: true}
```

**環境:**
Laravel 5.5
PHP 7.0
Apache 2.4
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03

Answer (score 0):

`.env`ファイルの中でAPP_URLを設定してみる。
たとえば、`APP_URL=http://localhost`　=>　`APP_URL=https://localhost` です。

Answer (score 0):

最近、nginxの設定で、似た事象を体験しましたので、参考になると思いコメントします。
リダイレクトの設定で301を戻すと、ブラウザ側でPOSTメソッドをGETメソッドに変更してリダイレクトされるようです。
私の場合、リダイレクトの設定で、307か、308を戻すように設定を変更することで解決しました。

[【徹底解説】ステータスコード3xxについて詳しく](https://envader.plus/article/31)